# Starting EventMachine from another file

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I wrote a simple EventMachine server like this one:

```
EventMachine.run do
  EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => HOST, :port => PORT) do |ws|
    # snip...
  end
end
```

Now, I would like to trigger it from another file in another directory. If EventMachine would be a simple Ruby class I would add a `run` (or something) class method and do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$LOAD_PATH << "./lib"
require "my_event_machine"
MyEventMachine.run
```

Any idea how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Is bash an option? You could always call it from bash. It's not the most elegant solution, but it works well.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I use now. I shell out but I am looking for a Ruby solution.

Comment: What issue do you have by wrapping your `EventMachine.run` code inside custom class `MyEventMachine.run` and calling it from another ruby file? Just trying to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks Alex, you are right, I needed a wrapper. Schmurfy proposes the same solution. I am sorry I can accept yours as your hint pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already had the solution:

my_app.rb:

```
class MyApp
  def run
    EM.run do
      EM::WebSocket.start(:host => HOST, :port => PORT) do |ws|
        # snip...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

run.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$LOAD_PATH << "./lib"
require "my_app"
MyApp.new.run
```

Comment: Thanks, I was close, but not close enough to see the solution. :)

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that EM.run just execute the given block if the reactor is already running without doing anything else which is really handy when implementing libraries or reusable code.